# Class with dynamic_attr() cannot pass __dict__ to the external scope

Tags: pybind11

### Reproducible example code

My c++ code is very simple:

```cpp
struct A
{   
    A()
    {
        this->a = 0;
    }
    py::int_ a;
};

struct B
{   
    B() {}
    A sa;
};


PYBIND11_MODULE(libdemo_ext, m)
{
    py::class_<A>(m, "A", py::dynamic_attr())
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("a", &A::a);
    py::class_<B>(m, "B", py::dynamic_attr())
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("sa", &B::sa);
}
```

When I use it in python like this:

```py
def func(b):
    sa = b.sa
    sa.pa = 'hello'

b = B()
func(b)
print(b.sa.pa)
```

and result is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(b.sa.pa)
AttributeError: 'libdemo_ext.A' object has no attribute 'pa'
```

But if I use it like this:

```py
def func(b):
    sa = b.sa
    sa.pa = 'hello'

b = B()
sa = b.sa
func(b)
print(b.sa.pa)
```

everythis is ok.

I have A class with dynamic_attr, And B class with dynamic_attr and A object.
But I cannot trans A's dynamic feature by B.

Answer (score 0):

pybind11 tracks bound objects and reuses them if the type and C++ address match. That's why the second case works. I do not know the exact use case that you are describing, but if the attribute is always added in a function, then you can make sure the reference stays alive by tying it to the lifetime of the 'b' object. Example:

```
def func(b):
    b._sa = b.sa
    b.sa.pa = 'hello'
```

or:

```
def func(b):
    sa = b.sa
    b.__dict__['sa'] = sa
    sa.pa = 'hello'
```

If you have many objects of type 'A', the second approach will be more efficient.